# How to chain two VPNs at the same time?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I bought two VPN software, VPN1 and VPN2. VPN1 have many available IPs but most are blocked at my location. VPN2 has fewer IPs but I can connect to them more easily.

I want to chain the two VPNs so that I can use the various IPs of VPN1. What I do is: run VPN2 and connect it to one of its servers; then run VPN1 and connect to one of its servers.  Since VPN2 is connected before VPN1 is connected, the connection of VPN1 is not blocked and successful. The problem is when I visit whatismyip.com, it always shows the ip of the VPN2's server so I cannot utilize the plenty IPs of VPN1.

I think the traffic route is my computer->vpn2's server->vpn1's server, but the reality seems my computer->vpn1's server->vpn2's server, or my computer->vpn2's server?

How can I do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by chaining VPNs? Why not just using VPN1 and canceling the VPN2 account?

Comment: Because VPN1 is blocked here and I cannot connect to it directly.

Comment: I see. You have to provide more information, otherwise we will not be able to help you. What OS are you using? How have you configured the VPNs? How does your IP / route settings look like when you are (1) not connected to a VPN (2) connected to VPN2 and (3) connected to VPN1 over VPN2? What you effectively try to set up is your own version of "onion routing". As a note: My approach would be to cancel VPN2, rent a VPS instead, set up VPN1 on it as a SOCKS proxy and forward the SOCKS port via SSH to my local machine.

Comment: There is no real benefit of doing what you suggest other than making the connection unnecessarily slow. That said, you can't really chain the VPN connections either, because the VPN tunnels all internet traffic on your pc towards the internet through its tunnel, so both VPN providers will battle for the connection creating an unstable connection, or simply lose and the other client gets it. If you are not happy with either VPN solution, search for a 3rd one, and cancel both vpn1 and vpn2.

Comment: @LPChip I agree that the setup OP strives for is most probable unnecessarily complex and will have bad performance. However, at least under Linux it is definitely possible to be implemented.

Comment: @dirdi It is interesting that the two VPN chain works for some times but does not work for other times. Is there a way to manually config the route in Windows 10, i.e., let the traffic go through VPN2, VPN1 in order?

Comment: We will not be able to help you as long as you do not provide more information, see my second comment above.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11, I have tested the use of 2 total different VPN solutions simultaneously.
No problem, but when checking the active IP address only that supplied by the last started VPN server occurs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your statement is clear. Bad bot